# Installing openswan unattended on Ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu, debian

I am writing shell scirpt on Ubuntu to install openswan:

```
echo "openswan openswan/install_x509_certificate boolean false" | debconf-set-selections
apt-get install openswan
```

It will prompt this message. And I should press "Enter" to continue.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/saiq-xh/8034933746/

Is there any way to ignore the infomation using script?